# How to filter alphabetic values from a String column in Pyspark Dataframe?

Tags: python, validation, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a string column that I need to filter. I need to obtain all the values that have letters or special characters in it.

Initial column:

| id |
| --- |
| 12345 |
| 23456 |
| 3940A |
| 19045 |
| 2BB56 |
| 3(40A |

Expected output:

| id |
| --- |
| 3940A |
| 2BB56 |
| 3(40A |

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the simple digits regex can solve your problem. `^\d+$` would catch all values that is entirely digits.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.where(F.regexp_extract('id', '^\d+$', 0) == '').show()

+-----+
|   id|
+-----+
|3940A|
|2BB56|
|3(401|
+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was very vague, so here is the best answer that I can give:

```
df_filtered = df.filter(any(not c.isdigit() for c in df.id))
```